# Create and start a thread of a Java web service operation

Tags: java, multithreading, web-services

Can i create and start a thread from inside a web service operation of a Java Web Application normally?If yes should that thread class be in the classes of the Web Application or the Java Application that consumes the service?

Comment: This doesn't make any sense. What do you mean by *package* in this context?

Comment: I mean the package of the classes contained in my Web Application. Should i have my thread there or at the application that consumes the web service?

Comment: Where do you want the thread started ? on the server (Where your webservice is deployed and running) ? or at the client(consumer) end?

Comment: @ringbearer: at the server, if it is possible

Comment: Why do you want to kick off a separate thread? Do you want to run an asychronous job?

Comment: @PaulMedcraft: yes, the searate thread is absolutely necessary for my app

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The server JVM will certainly need to load the classes used by your new thread, so they will need to be somewhere on the server classpath. Unless you also need to use some or all of them on the client application there will be no need for them to be on the client classpath. How you name and package them is up to you but if they are only used inside the server app it would make sense to use similar names or the same parent packages.

You should consider using something like Quartz to manage your threads and depending on what you want this web service to do, consider using JMS/MDB instead.